# MySQL Lock Database on Slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-workbench, database-replication, mysql-5.6

I am doing data replication. I have one master server and one slave server and my data is successfully replicated from master to slave. Now i want to lock my slave server database for writing.

I used `LOCKED TABLE mytable READ` and it successfully locked my table on slave for instance "myIns1". But when i open MySQL using other instance and i try to write on same database so it writes easily and sometimes also hangs. I want my slave server database to be locked completely for all MYSQL instances and users.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **read-only** option in the slave. This prevents users with no SUPER privilege from updating the database. Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_read-only) for more:

> Cause the slave to permit no updates except from slave threads or from users having the SUPER privilege. On a slave server, this can be useful to ensure that the slave accepts updates only from its master server and not from clients. This variable does not apply to TEMPORARY tables.

Comment: You can set it in my.cnf.

Comment: where in my.cnf? please can you write the line or code. 
thankyou.

Comment: You can write `read-only = 1` in the file. If you're using Linux, my.cnf is usually located in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, otherwise in Windows it's located inside the data directory. You can see the command line used by the Windows service to see where exactly. Also, in Windows, it's usually called `my.ini` instead of `my.cnf`.

Comment: ok and can i also use `use mydb; flush tables with read lock;`. is it also do the same thing??

Answer (score 0):

Which version you have using it ? And MySQL Replication has option to replicate only particular databases , configure it .

Other option remove access for not required database , but it will show error when not required database having any changes in master . It will write binlog and send to slave server .

Comment: i am using mysql 5.6 and yes i am replicating particular database i.e "mydb" and configured it also. I just want to lock "mydb" on Slave Server for write by all instances amd users of slave??